# Use Cursor and If statement to store and replace data

Tags: sql, foxpro, cursors

I am transforming FoxPro code into SQL for a report. The current FoxPro Code is below. I need to be able to create two cursors, store data from two fields in them and check them against a table for replacing data. Can anyone help me transform this code into sql for sql server?

[FoxPro Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlI3C.png)

```
CREATE Cursor delete_cursor(salesno c(6), release_number c(3))     
SELECT table1    
GOTO TOP    
lcsono= table1.salesno
lcrelease = table1.release_number     
GOTO 2    
SCAN REST

   IF table1.salesno == lcsono AND table1.release_number <> "000"
      AND lcrelease = "000"

      SELECT delete_cursor
      APPEND BLANK
      REPLACE table1.salesno WITH lcsono
      REPLACE table1.release_number WITH lcrelease
      SELECT table1
   ENDIF

   lcsono = table1.salesno
   lcrelease= table1.release_number
ENDSCAN

SELECT delete_cursor
INDEX on ALLTRIM(delete_cursor.salesno) + ALLTRIM(delete_cursor.releaseno)
  TAG tagdelete

SELECT table1
GOTO TOP
SCAN
   IF SEEK(ALLTRIM(table1.salesno) + ALLTRIM (table1.salesno), 
      "delete_cursor", "tagdelete")

      REPLACE table1.delflag WITH "Y"
   ENDIF
ENDSCAN
```

[My SQL Server Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m6ka.png)

```
DECLARE CURSOR @fsono char(6)
update table1.salesno Set 
      table1.salesno = @fsono
   where 
          @fsono = table1.salesno 
      AND table1.release_number <> "000" 
      AND lcrelease = "000" 

DECLARE CURSOR @release char(6)

update table1.release_number Set 
      table1.release_number = @release
   where 
          @fsono = table1.salesno 
      AND table1.release_number <> "000" 
      AND @release = "000"
```

Comment: Please, no images (or links to them.) Most people here want formatted text.

Comment: Sorry, I have entered text

Comment: I am not so familiar with FoxPro, But if you can provide the data you currently have and the desired result, I'm sure we can help with the solution.

Comment: I am fluent in both, however what you are doing is really a hard way of doing... both in VFP and SQL.  The syntax in VFP doesn't even look right with the REPLACE.  You have the cursor selected for a new blank record and try to replace the TABLE1 columns which is incorrect.  Can you please edit your post and describe in simple terms what you want.. Ex: The first record in the table is a control record.  Leave it alone.  From there, I want to delete all records that … whatever your criteria is.  In VFP and SQL, it should be much easier than the structures you have offered here at this time.

Comment: The VFP code is both correct and executable. I already have the report in VFP I am simply recreating it in sql. The second part of the VFP code (Index ALLTrim) is to set a column that I have to Y so I can select all data that contains N in that column instead of Y..  the object is to remove all master releases from a sales table

Comment: Also don't confuse cursors in VFP and MSSQL, the equivalent of a VFP cursor in MSSQL is either a table variable or a temporary table.

Comment: @NightCode312 The code provided does not execute; it fails on the INDEX statement which refers to the `releaseno` field, which is actually named `release_number`
In addition, the code (as provided) does nothing but append blank rows into the `delete_cursor` as the replace points to `table1` Now, that being said, the rub with converting it to sql will be ensuring that the ordering is the same. Most likely when this runs `table1` is in a very specific order causing the RBAR scan to find the expected records; It would be helpful if you included an example of some rows from `table1`